# Why does this recursion execute the way it does?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Code snippet is from Eloquent Javascript:

```
function findSolution(target) {
    function find(current, history) {
        if (current == target) {
            return history;
        }
        else if (current > target) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) || 
                    find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
        }
    }
    return find(1, "1");
}

console.log(findSolution(13));
```

I debugged the code to see if I can understand it. Didn't work.

I inspected the call stack. Seems that after the "return null;", the program executes the previous call, but this time considering else return as "call1 is null || call2".

After going back through the call stack twice (at that point current is 6 and history is "(1 + 5)"), call1 no longer returns null (since current is 6 and history is "(1 + 5)"), so how come current and history just take the values from call1 and execute call2 with those values ?

Also, how does the program decide to execute call2 in the first place, since at that point call1 doesn't return null ? (I am picturing an infinite recursion, but that is for whatever reason, obviously not the case)

What am I missing ?

Comment: This looks very much like a jug of 5l and 3l and some coursework...

Comment: @MisterJojo Of course that is recursion?

Comment: "*how come current and history just take the values from call1 and execute call2 with those values*" - they never take the results of the first call, they just take the values from the current stack frame to which call1 returned.

Comment: "*how does the program decide to execute call2 in the first place, since at that point call1 doesn't return null ?*" - it *does*. The second `find()` call is only executed if the first `find()`  call was returning `null`.

Comment: @Bergi please see my answer to my question and if you agree, based on the other question you linked and your two answers, I think I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
findSequence(13)
    find(1, "1")
        find(1 + 5, "(1 + 5)") // this becomes null, because both of its nested stacks are null, because both of their nested stacks are null
            find(6 + 5, "((1 + 5) + 5)") // this becomes null, because both of its nested stacks are null
                find(11 + 5, "(((1 + 5) + 5) + 5)"
                    current > target: return null
                find(11 * 3, "(((1 + 5) + 5) * 3)"
                    current > target: return null
            find(6 * 3, "((1 + 5) * 3)") // this becomes null, because both of its nested stacks are null
                find(18 + 5, "(((1 + 5) * 3) + 5)")
                    current > target: return null
                find(18 * 3, "(((1 + 5) * 3) * 3)")
                    current > target: return null
        find(1 * 3, "(1 * 3)") 
            find(3 + 5, "((1 * 3) + 5)")
                find(8 + 5, "(((1 * 3) + 5) + 5)")
                    current == target: return "(((1 * 3) + 5) + 5)"
```

So, would you say this is accurate ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*is no longer null*" - it's a completely new call that never *was* `null`. But yes, these calls are the ones that return the eventual result.

Comment: That's something that confused the brain out of me...
Now I get that, because it is a part of new stack, it has NO PREVIOUS STATE, which I thought was the case at first.